# Hi, I am trying to replicate sumif function in excel for python dataframe with specific column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My target on daily basis is 250. For any given date, if the cum-daily_result has reached 250 then subsequent rows should have only 250 as expected results

In below table column 'ID' to 'cum_daily_result' are the input in data frame. The expected output is computed manually in column 'expected_daily_result'

[image]

I tried the below code, but not giving the expected result,

```
if df['cum_daily_result'][-1] >= 250:
    expected_daily_result = df['cum_daily_result'][-1]
else:
    expected_daily_result  = df['cum_daily_result']
```

Comment: make simple exampe text not image for answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [.clip(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html)

```
    expected_daily_result  = df.cum_daily_result.clip(upper=250)
```

Comment: Hi. This is helpful if daily cum result is higher than 250. But when it goes on negative side, it returns the negative value. For example ID 95 ie 3rd row cum_daily_result is -790 hence it is returning the same. But since the 250 is already achieved for the day, i need the expected result to be 250 only after the 1st row (where cum_daily_result) for particular day is reached 250. could you please advice

Answer (score 0):

make simple example text not image

example:

```
data = [['a', 250, 250], ['a', 250, 500], ['a', -1290, -790],
        ['b', -1392, -1392], ['b', 250, -1142], ['b', 250, -892], ['b', 2238, 1346],
        ['b', 250, 1596], ['c', 2477, 2477], ['c', -3813, -1336], ['c', 250, -1086]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

output(`df`):

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       250     250
1   a       250     500
2   a       -1290   -790
3   b       -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142
5   b       250     -892
6   b       2238    1346
7   b       250     1596
8   c       2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336
10  c       250     -1086
```

use `groupby`

```
idx = df[df['col3'] >= 250].groupby('col1').head(1).index
df.loc[idx, 'col4'] = 1
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col4'].bfill() * df['col3']
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col4'].ffill().astype('int')
```

output(`df`)

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   a       250     250     250
1   a       250     500     250
2   a       -1290   -790    250
3   b       -1392   -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142   -1142
5   b       250     -892    -892
6   b       2238    1346    1346
7   b       250     1596    1346
8   c       2477    2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336   2477
10  c       250     -1086   2477
```

Comment: Hi. This is amazing. It is very helpful. Could you please advice me how to find cumulative value of all dates. Ie. maximum of 'col 1' 'a'+'b'+'c' in new column. Ie a - 250 + b - 1346 + c - 2477 in new column

Comment: I think you're a newb, I just made exmaple by myself and answered it only once. make an exampe like me

Comment: Hi. The above code works fine if the first row of column 13 is >= 250, but if the first row of column is less than 250 for eg., -700, then i get the following error "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"